# Sorting Core Data objects by transformable attribute with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm displaying objects stored in Core Data in a UITableView and am having problems sorting these objects by one of the object's transformable attributes. I should point out that I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController as the controller between the Core Data store and my table view. When I was simply using an array to hold all of my objects, I could sort them without any problems at all. I'm using an FRC because I need the data grouped in sections with section headers and the FRC makes that very easy.

Let's call these objects I'm sorting "Measurement" objects. Each Measurement object has a distance attribute. That distance attribute is of a custom class, EPHDistance, so it's set up in the Core Data model as a Transformable attribute.

To make a long story short, the sorting of Measurement objects by their distance *does* work, but only after I've edited an object that's stored by Core Data or if I add a new object to the store. After editing the store and returning to my table that lists all the Measurement objects in order, everything works great. It's just the initial launch and viewing of the table view where the objects aren't sorted properly. I've actually placed an NSLog statement in my EPPDistance -compare: method and it's not getting called when I sort the objects until I add/edit an object in the Core Data store. For what it's worth, if I sort theses Measurement objects by their "date" attribute, which is an NSDate, it works great right out of the gate.

I'm not super experienced with Core Data and this is my first real attempt at using an NSFetchedResultsController so I'm a little baffled by this. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

You could create an optional method in your `Measurement` class call `-(NSString*)distanceCompareString`, which returns a string that will help you sort from your `EPHDistance` object. The in your NSSortDescriptor, you just use `distanceCompareString` as your sort key.

Comment: You can’t just arbitrarily add a method to an NSManagedObject subclass and use that method in a SortDescriptor. After further investigation, you *can’t* sort NSManagedObjects based on a transformable attribute. Why sorting by the transformable attribute works *after* I update the data store is confusing me. Looks like I’m going to have to pull out all the objects I want to view and store them in an array and sort them that way. Not sure how I’m going to deal with creating the table’s sections... Thanks for the attempt, though :)

Comment: Well, I use this method to provide table sections name. I thought it would work as well. Too bad.